# Bindings and Proxy IIS and Tomcat parameters not working

Tags: web-services, tomcat, iis, binding, proxy

I'm setting up three services on my localhost, This will be moved to a server once I manage to fix the last of my problems. What I'm trying to do is to set it up so that all services are accessed through port 80.

One of the services is hosted in Tomcat and the other two are hosted in IIS.

I've used URL Rewrite to proxy the requests going to the Tomcat service so that this is now accessed through port 80.

I can use Bindings in IIS to force the other two services to also be accessed through port 80.

This is the intended outcome:

- jft.serviceadmin.localhost will access one IIS service
- jft.api.localhost will access the other IIS Service
- jft.generatepdf.localhost will access the Tomcat service

I've added these URL's to the host file and everything up to this point is working great. When I access the Above URL's in my browser I get the expected results.

**BUT**, when I, from the client, try to access jft.generatepdf.localhost with a couple of parameters (ID's, Key's etc). I get an error saying that the unit id "null" cannot be found. This error message is generated by my own service so I don't expect anyone here to be able to read anything out of it. what I'm asking however, is if anyone can come up with an explanation of why this might be happening?

If I remove the bindings for the two IIS Services and do the same thing, it works great. The ID(s) is passed along to my db as intended and I get a PDF in return (as is the purpose of generatePdf:) )

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself so if anyone runs in to this problem at some point, make sure to try the solution described:

The native IIS Services that have bindings for port 80 (in my case jft.api.localhost and jft.serviceadmin.localhost), need URL Rewrite rules added in the same way as the proxy service needs it.

So by having them hosted on two separate ports (lets say 8181 and 8282) along with the bindings for port 80, you can apply the same technique as used when adding rewrite rule for the tomcat service.